# Sed to add blanks in every line

Tags: shell

I want to insert 4 blanks in a text named test.

```
sed 's/^/  \{4\}/'  test
```

Why it can't work?how can i do?

how about  i want to add 10 blanks or 20 blanks?

```
sed 's/^/    /' test  #can work ,but not well done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nneonneo explained why your script didn't work.  It is fairly well known how to pad lines on the left with spaces to achieve lines of a fixed width, but adding the same number of blanks to the left a line for every line in sed is a different problem.

If you can bear to use something other than sed,

Or you can use `ruby`

```
ruby -e 'ARGF.each {|l| puts (" " * 4) + l}' test
```

Or you can use `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=0; i<4; i++) printf(" "); print $0}' test
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'printf "%s%s", (" " x 4), $_' test
```

EDIT: I would like to see a pure `sed` solution.  Using the conditional branch (`t`) seems useful for padding, but not to do what you ask.

Answer (score 2):

`{n}` repeats don't work in replacement patterns.

Just do

```
sed 's/^/    /' test
```